# addClass doesn't work on iphone Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, web

```
  // changing navbar background-color by scrolling
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $("#tab-nav").addClass("tab-scroll");
  } else {
    $("#tab-nav").removeClass("tab-scroll");
  }
});

.tab-scroll {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
```

Above are my code for jquery and CSS. I want to change the background color of navbar whenever it reaches a certain height, the code works on every browser in desktop, and it also works on iPhone safari. but it doesn't work on iPhone chrome. Can you guys help me fix it? is there any trick that can make the code compatible for any browser?

thank

Comment: For anyone that want's to do some mobile testing, [here's an example Codepen](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/mKMaxX). It seems to be tied to listening for the scroll on iOS Chrome, as  I can't seem to get it to trigger with `$(window).scroll()`, `$(window).on('scroll')`, `window.addEventListener('scroll')` as well as with `document` or `body` instead of `window` on each of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Vanilla JS`:

```
function scrollFunctions() {
    var
        pageY = window.pageYOffset,
        tab = document.getElementById('tab-nav');

    /** @Sticky Header **/
    if (pageY > 20) {
        tab.classList.add('tab-scroll');
    }
    else if (pageY <= 20) {
        tab.classList.remove('tab-scroll');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    scrollFunctions();
});
```

Comment: This made no difference for me.