# jQuery addClass does not work on Chrome running on Andriod

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264151/jquery-addclass-not-working-on-mobile-browser) question which is similar except it does not specify the browser and OS. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865224/addclass-doesnt-work-on-iphone-chrome/50867340) question which describes the same issue for Chrome running on iPhone (I have tried the accepted answer, which suggests using JavaScript instead of jQuery, and it made no difference).

What I want to do is to show/hide pagination buttons depending on the number of documents in the search result. This is the code:

```js
function showHidePagination(totalNoOfDocuments) {
    var paginationContainer = document.getElementById('paginationContainer');
    if (totalNoOfDocuments <= pageSize) {
        paginationContainer.classList.add('d-none');
        //$('#paginationContainer').addClass('d-none');    // <-- this did not work either
    } else {
        paginationContainer.classList.remove('d-none');
        //$('#paginationContainer').removeClass('d-none'); // <-- this did not work either
    }
}
```

When user clicks on *Search* button, an Ajax request is send to the server, the new results are fetched and then I call `showHidePagination()` and pass the total number of documents in the result. The function should hide the pagination if the total number of documents are less than `pageSize` (which is a constant variable).

The above code works in desktop and it does not work on Chrome running on Android. I have also seen [this document](https://grobmeier.solutions/jquery-workaround-when-addclass-is-not-repainted-29032013.html) which suggests `removeClass` works but `addClass` does not work... it suggests solving issue by negating the logic and using `removeClass` but I cannot see how to toggle `d-none` class this way...

I am not able to understand why is this issue happening? And how should I resolve this?

Comment: I would try using paginationContainer.addClass('d-none') and  paginationContainer.removeClass('d-none'). Not sure what the underlying issue is though so this may or may not resolve it.

Comment: @JohnMartinez: as you can see in the code, I have already tried it